# How to insert into googl docs the location of the current file?

Tags: google-docs

In MS-Word I can add the location of the file in my computer
also, last edited time/date?
Is there a way to do the same in google docs?

Comment: Where is this doc stored? In Google Drive? Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: no I can not share that doc. I have nothing so far as I could not find any function like this in google docs. that is why I am asking

Comment: Do you want to use the Docs API, or the UI?

Comment: UI pls .........

Comment: If you want to use UI, then the solution is to use Apps script to create a custom function, and optionally a menu item for the function.

Comment: can you pls direct me on how to do this?

Comment: Check my answer, if you would like to know how to use Apps Script to write a file property in a google doc, I can help.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no way to do this. Google docs files are stored in the cloud in Drive, and the references to its location could be a parent folder (bear in mind it can have multiple parents).

On the other hand if your doc is "stored" in your machine, it really is a link to open the file in a web browser from the Google Drive where it lives.

So as far as writing the location of the file within you machine into the file, it is not possible. 
You could with Apps Script and the Drive service, get from the file metadata the parent(s), and doing this recursively to build the folder structure where the file resides.

This is kind of overkill, and don't know how useful.
**Note:** The unique identifier for files in Google Drive is the Id of the file, perhaps you might want to write the file Id into the file, that is simpler, and it is a unique identifier for your doc.

---

**References**:

- [Drive API File resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) (All these properties are accessible through the Drive service of Apps Script)
- [Apps Script fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/fundamentals-codelabs)
- [Apps script Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)